# How to interpret gaps in chrome flame charts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, flamegraph

I'm trying to better understand how to interpret chrome flame charts.
In the below chart `_changeHandler` is shown as four distinct blocks. 
However I know for fact that it's only being called once.

I saw a similar question here, which claims this might be a bug, but that was four  years ago:
[What are this gap mean in Chrome devtools profile flame chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627082/what-are-this-gap-mean-in-chrome-devtools-profile-flame-chart)

[image]

**Question:**
In which case would chrome perf tools show gaps in the flame chart for the same function call ?

The real problem is that it really invalidates the entire graph. The bottom of the graph fragments but the top parts are the same function. I can't figure out how to make sense of that at all.

When using cpu throttling, the problem becomes exponentially worse.
Look at the second picture, it's the same operation as the first graph, but with cpu throttling set to 5x slowdown.
The fragmented bar under "Function Call" is a single function call, for some reason it's fragmented in hundreds of sections.

[image]

Comment: What's your methodology for knowing that it's only called once?

Comment: @KayceBasques A log statement.

Comment: Apparently it reflects the internal implementation of throttling. Looks like a bug anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Thing is, we get the JS function data by sampling (unlike native events that we get by instrumenting start/stop). So internally it's just 4 samples that landed into the said function. We don't know if it was executed once or 4 times or 100 times, but we do our best to glue them so as it appeared as one call as long as the samples are adjacent.
>
> But sometimes this logic mysteriously fails. Most of the time, this is because of some problems while sampling the JS stack (if some inlined or native function is on top, we sometimes fail to unwind the stack properly).

Source: Chat with a DevTools engineer

If you want to [privately submit a url / steps to reproduce](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSef3LpF0JcwQLCUABaQAdNFItKEQcVosRCrLltk930DRUC1kA/viewform), the team can check it out. They thought they fixed this category of bugs.

Comment: Thank you for explaining ! I would love to provide further feedback but it looks like I'm not allowed to access that google doc document. I live in mountain view tough, maybe I can stop by :D ?

Comment: I added an additional screenshot to really demonstrate how this becomes problematic for the whole graph.

Comment: This was driving me insane! Look at this graph: [flame chart, no throttle](https://i.imgur.com/5DSX5cB.png). Trying to debug this, I thought RequireJS was loading `AppHeader` a lot of times. Well, at least now I know there's really only one call.