# Reading CPU profile snapshot in Chrome DevTools: is it multiple calls or one?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, cpu-usage, callstack, code-profiling

I'm profiling an application and I'm not sure how should I interpret the call chart. As far as I understand if a bar is split into several ones on the next line, that means that the top function calls underlying functions several times.

I mean, when I see the following in the chart:

```
| fn1                                                   |
| fn2     | fn2                 | fn2        | fn2      |
| ...                                                   |
| value   | value               | value      | value    |
```

I read it as `fn1` was called only once and `value` was called four times inside that `fn1` call.

The thing is if I insert `console.log` into that `value` function, I see it called exactly once. So what does that mean, that I have many columns with `value`?

[image: profile chart]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627082/what-are-this-gap-mean-in-chrome-devtools-profile-flame-chart seems like an explanation (gaps mean nothing), but that answer is 4+ years old.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interpret gaps in chrome flame charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008547/how-to-interpret-gaps-in-chrome-flame-charts)